# Problemas de imagem blob e cache

Tags: php, imagem, laravel-5, blob

Estou tendo problemas com imagens `BLOB`, a programação está sendo feita com o framework `Laravel` na `versão 5.2`. O mini mundo é seguinte:

Faço o upload do arquivo e salvo apenas um `BLOB`, não faço nenhuma validação de tamanho ou algo do tipo apenas efetuo o save do `BLOB` e outros dados como nome da imagem, etc...

Algo utilizar a imagem juntamente da `tag` `html <img src="MEU BLOB"/>`, um comportamento estranho é acionado, de forma aleatória e não sequenciada as imagens não aparece. Ao verificar o código ele está escrito de forma perfeita, porém não é compilado.

Fazendo alguns teste percebi que quando limpo o cache do navegador, algumas imagens aparecem e outras ainda sim continuam sumidas. Para validar este teste limpei varias vezes e todas as vezes, horas apareciam umas imagens horas apareciam outra. Identifiquei com isto que provavelmente o cache tem um tamanho, e as imagens estavam enchendo este cache devido a isto horas apareciam e horas não algumas imagens.

Ai vem minha questão:

Teria algumas forma de solucionar isto sem fazer o `resize` da imagem, pois a ideia é ter imagem de tamanhos variados, o certo seria diminuir a qualidade da imagem.

A titulo de increnmento a minha pergunta, hoje estou salvando a imagem assim:

```
    $file = $request->file('BLOB');
    $name = $file->getPathName();
    $file = base64_encode(file_get_contents($name));
    $src = 'data: image/jpg;base64,'.$file;

    $imagem = Imagem::create([
        'CdProduto' => $request->CdProduto,
        'NmImagem' => $request->NmImagem,
        'DscImagem' => $request->DscImagem,
        'BLOB' => $src,
        'FlgPrincipal' => $request->FlgPrincipal
    ]);
```

Preciso da certeza que todas as imagens serão carregadas, devido ao projeto ser referente ao produto.

Faço uma pergunta seria mais viável não salvar esta imagem em `BLOB`, e sim um arquivo fixo no `disco` ? Ou os dois tipos, é uma solução plausível ?

Comment: Normalmente salva-se no banco somente o `path` da imagem e a imagem em si é salva em um diretório. E quando precisa recuperar essa imagem basta recuperar o `path` do banco e carrega-la.

Comment: Sim, mas e no caso de precisar utilizar esta imagem via json, por exemplo em um app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gravar as imagens diretamente no banco de dados é, na maioria das vezes, errado conceitualmente. **Deve-se evitar com todas as forças gravar imagens em blobs de banco de dados.** O que se deve guardar no banco de dados é um URI (*Universal Resource Identifier*) indicando a localização da imagem, melhor ainda se colocar uma URI relativa, o que facilita relocação em massa das imagens no futuro.

**Algumas desvantagens de se guardar imagens em banco de dados**

1. Crescimento absurdo (e desnecessário) do banco de dados
2. Maior custo no uso do banco de dados
3. Dificuldade de escalonamento horizontal
4. Dificuldade de processamento em massa das imagens
5. Necessidade de implementar cache de imagens por conta própria
6. Impossibilidade de uso de CDN (Content Delivery Network)
7. Impossibilidade de usufruir dos preços baixos de armazenamento na nuvem
8. Impossibilidade de usufruir dos benefícios de serviços como Amazon S3, CloudFront, Azure Storage, etc.
9. Não poderá escrever HTML direto apontando para a URL das imagens
10. Suas imagens passam a ser conteúdo dinâmico e não estático (gasta CPU do seu aplicativo/servidor o simples fato de servir uma imagem).

E essas são apenas as que lembrei imediatamente ao escrever essa resposta!

**NOTA**: *Irei detalhar cada uma dessas desvantagens a medida que aprimoro a resposta, porém preciso de mais tempo para tal. Portanto, volte à essa resposta de tempos em tempos se tiver interesse em saber mais sobre cada uma dessas desvantagens.*

**Como enviar a imagem para APPS**

Você não precisa enviar as imagens para APPs através de JSON. Praticamente **todos** os framerworks para desenvolvimento de aplicativos conseguem carregar imagens diretamente das URLs, tornando trivial carregar suas imagens se elas estiverem gravadas em servidores de arquivos/conteúdo como o Amazon S3, ou Azure Storage.

Em android, por exemplo, para carregar uma imagem qualquer basta utilizar o seguinte código em Java da **excelente** biblioteca [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide):

```
  Glide
    .with(this)
    .load(url) // qualquer URL acessível!!! 
    .into(meuImageView); // ImageView é um objeto que exibe imagens no android
```

A biblioteca já toma conta de usar um cliente HTTP avançado, que permite acesso via HTTPS, múltiplas tentativas em caso de falha no download, espera restabelecimento da conexão de internet, etc. Ou seja, muito mais fácil do que passar a imagem como JSON, o que tornaria o tamanho da chamada muito maior (uma ordem de magnitude maior) e ainda exigiria código para interpretar o JSON no cliente. Já enviar a URL diretamente permite que o cliente a exiba sem dificuldades.

Ainda assim, caso queira enviar a imagem como JSON, nada lhe impede de fazer um "GET" no seu servidor e ler a imagem como um array de bytes (igual faria com o blob) e então encapsular isso numa resposta JSON. Contudo, repito: isso é um erro conceitual!

**Para gravar a imagem na Amazon S3**

O Laravel fornece uma poderosa abstração de sistema de arquivos utilizando o pacote [Flysystem](https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem) criado por Frank de Jonge. A documentação dessa funcionalidade pode ser vista na página: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/filesystem (foge ao escopo dessa resposta duplicar as informações de configuração dessa biblioteca. Basta ler a documentação)

Podemos usar automaticamente as abstrações do sistema de arquivos para gravar diretamente no Amazon S3. Abaixo vemos uma forma de fazer isso.

Inclua o use onde necessário:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
```

Modifique o código original para:

```
$file = $request->file('BLOB');
$name = $file->getPathName();
// o método putFile retorna a URL do arquivo conforme armazenado
// estou assumindo que $name tenha o caminho para o arquivo sendo gravado
$url = Storage::putFile('imagens', new File($name), 'public');

$imagem = Imagem::create([
    'CdProduto' => $request->CdProduto,
    'NmImagem' => $request->NmImagem,
    'DscImagem' => $request->DscImagem,
    'URL' => $url,
    'FlgPrincipal' => $request->FlgPrincipal
]);
```

Note que você precisa já ter criado um *Bucket* no Amazon S3 e configurado, de acordo com a documentação já referenciada do Laravel, o `Filesystem` com os dados do seu bucket e conta da Amazon.

**Para gravar no disco local**

A mesma abstração de sistema de arquivo do Laravel permite gravar no sistema de arquivo local. Inclusive, esse é o comportamento padrão. Portanto basta deixar a configuração como padrão que suas imagens serão gravadas, automaticamente, no caminho: `storage/app/public`. Diretamente da documentação:

> The public disk is intended for files that are going to be publicly
>   accessible. By default, the public disk uses the local driver and
>   stores these files in storage/app/public. To make them accessible from
>   the web, you should create a symbolic link from public/storage to
>   storage/app/public. This convention will keep your publicly accessible
>   files in one directory that can be easily shared across deployments
>   when using zero down-time deployment systems like Envoyer.

A única mudança no código seria a remoção do `'public'` da chamada de gravação da imagem:

```
$url = Storage::putFile('imagens', new File($name));
```

Por isso essa abstração de sistema de arquivo é tão poderosa: basta modificar a configuração para gravar no disco local, ou no Amazon S3, por exemplo.

**Nota sobre hospedagem**

Se você for hospedar esse sistema em uma hospedagem compartilhada, tome cuidado pois você pode não ter acesso completo ao sistema de arquivos. Ou pode ter acesso, mas com muito pouco espaço. Além disso o sistema de arquivo pode ser limpo, automaticamente, de tempos em tempos. E pode ser difícil fazer backup das imagens, pois pode não ter como fazer FTP para o sistema de arquivo de onde o sistema está hospedado. E, no final, você pode ter acesso ao sistema de arquivo e ele não ser visível publicamente, o que impossibilitará de repassar as imagens através de uma URL pública.

Minha sugestão é usar hospedagens profissionais de verdade, e contratar serviços de armazenamento de arquivos, como os da Amazon com o Amazon S3. As vantagens são enormes e o custo baixíssimo (você paga menos de 0,12 (doze centavos) em média por Gigabyte!). E ganha os benefícios de ter as imagens acessíveis (e com controle de acesso se desejar) por URLs. Contudo, é preciso estudar, pelo menos, o básico do Amazon S3 para usá-lo corretamente, o que é bastante fácil no final das contas.

Comment: Poderia acrescentar em sua resposta, como faria esta utilização (salvando a imagem da melhor forma) como explicado por você em sua resposta ?

Comment: @RenanRodrigues vai depender muito da sua arquitetura! Onde você gravará essa imagem? Se você for gravar, por exemplo, em um blob do Azure tem que usar a biblioteca cliente deles para PHP. Se for gravar no Amazon S3, pode usar a ótima biblioteca flysystem.php. Praticamente todas as suas perguntas podem ser respondidas na documentação do Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/filesystem (mas vou atualizar a resposta com uma sugestão de código, estimando como funciona sua arquitetura, de onde vem o arquivo para gravar, etc.)

Comment: Pretendo pega o serviço inicialmente com uma hospedagem compartilhada, tipo localweb.

Comment: Me refiro a salvar a imagem em uma pasta especifica ou algo do tipo

Comment: @RenanRodrigues dei um exemplo para gravar em Amazon S3, porque achei que você trivial gravar em uma pasta. Não se abstenha de ler a documentação do laravel, porque cabe a você entender como isso funciona, senão vou simplesmente copiar a documentação de lá para cá e isso está fora do escopo da Stack Overflow! Ainda assim, para gravar no disco local você pode usar o próprio Flysystem. Ele grava, como informado no início da documentação, por padrão em `storage/app/public`. Agora, se vai hospedar numa Locaweb da vida, cuidado pois pode não ter acesso ao sistema de arquivo, ou não ter espaço!

Comment: @RenanRodrigues experimente ler a resposta em http://stackoverflow.com/a/29704990/285678  ...  Você precisa fazer o use correto. Como você estava lidando com arquivos antes?

Comment: é na verdade esta faltando algumas dependências, procurando achei esta https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-Flysystem estou seguindo mais vendo que ha muitas alterações, talvez seja viável para uma resposta mais completa, e de antemão saindo do contexto da pergunta mais utilizando como incremento seja legal colocar a parte de instalação. Vou ver se consigo fazer sozinho